# Performing spatial queries in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, wms, spatial-query

I have two Layers which I added to the map using WMS service. Is there a way to perform spatial queries using Lealflet, for example; Intersection, Distance...?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't. WMS layers are images(pixels). Points, Polygons, and lines can be spatially queried. If you can retrieve the layer as a WFS or geojson file then you have objects to query.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong. You can't perform that analysis on WMS.

For doing the above-mentioned task you must be bringing those layers from a database which many times may be postgis. Try to work with leaflet Geojson. 
For example

> select ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(linestring, polygon)) As wkt
>   from  ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING Z (2 2 6,1.5 1.5 7,1 1 8,0.5 0.5 8,0 0 10)') AS linestring
>    CROSS JOIN ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0 8, 0 1 8, 1 1 8, 1 0 8, 0 0 8))') AS polygon;

Bring these results as geojson and show it on your map.

Comment: Why st_astext() and not st_asgeojson()?